# What probability distribution models this race condition?

Tags: shell, files, pipe

Consider the following command:
`bash -c "echo x; cat 1" | tee 1`.

My understanding is that it would fork to a new shell, write `x` to stdout, write `file 1 not found` to stderr, exit and return control to the parent process, and write `x` to stdout and to `1`. Hence, I would expect the final output to be `x`, and the file `1` contains exactly the string `x`.

However, this is not the case. In actuality, the file `1` usually contains at least two instances of `x`, and sometimes thousands of lines of `x`s. On a batch test of running the command ten thousand times, the mean number of `x`s written to the file was 52.3, and the median was 1. What mechanic is causing this? What probability distribution models this behavior? I suspect that it is conditionally geometric and otherwise uniform.

Comment: It has to do with the timing of the execution of the left and right hand side of the pipeline. Both are started simultaneously, or close to it. If `tee` has opened the file for writing before `cat` opens it for reading, you may get many `x`-es in the file. In that case, the "loop" would end whenever `cat` reads faster than `tee` writes, reaching the end of the file.

Comment: From limited testing here, the average number of `x`s written to the file was of 4.35. I guess it will depends a lot on machine load.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very curious one, so I tried to investigate it with the help of strace. Ran your command in a loop 1000 times:

```
mkdir {000..999}
for i in {000..999}; do
echo $i
(cd $i; strace -f -o trace.log bash -c 'bash -c "echo x; cat 1" | tee 1 >/dev/null'; )
done
```

Found the file with the most lines (`wc -l */1 | sort -nr | head -n2`), and checked the corresponding `trace.log`. I can certainly see lots of:

```
7567  <... read resumed> "x\n", 8192)   = 2
7567  write(1, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  write(3, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  read(0,  <unfinished ...>
7568  read(3, "x\n", 131072)            = 2
7568  write(1, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  <... read resumed> "x\n", 8192)   = 2
7567  write(1, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  write(3, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  read(0,  <unfinished ...>
7568  read(3, "x\n", 131072)            = 2
7568  write(1, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  <... read resumed> "x\n", 8192)   = 2
7567  write(1, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  write(3, "x\n", 2)                = 2
7567  read(0,  <unfinished ...>
```

Where 7567 is `tee 1` and 7568 is `cat 1`. The two are definitely alternating, so yes, as suspected, this is all about the timing of the execution (and I imagine context switching) of the two commands.